# OGR: "ERROR 1: No field definitions found for '...', is it a table "

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, ogr

I am writing a script to test if the number of elements is equal in the input file of a process and in the output (database). This is my code:

```
def check_output(value, refcount, reftype):
    db, idsch, table = value.split('.')
    ident, schema = idsch.split('_')

    dsn = ogr.Open(get_connstr())
    if dsn is None:
        raise Exception("Reading data failed.")
    lyr = dsn.GetLayerByName('{}.{}'.format(idsch, table))
    if lyr is None:
        raise Exception("Could not find the layer.")
    count = lyr.GetFeatureCount()
    if count != refcount:
        raise Exception("The number of elements written to the database is different from the number of elements in the input file.")
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1: No field definitions found for 'buff_out', is it a table?
raise Exception("Could not find the layer.")
Exception: Could not find the layer.
```

The result of this (printing the argument of the GetLayerByName function):

```
print('{}.{}'.format(idsch, table)):
```

is this:

```
process-one-output_0489e558-eb28-11e7-a0d8-54ee758a7423.buff_out
```

If I understand it correctly, it sucessfully connects to the database but it cannot access the layer. Anyone knows what causes the error and how to solve it?